# Dynamic EF Where Clause raising ArgumentNullException

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to code a method that, in it's class given the values of some of the attributes, returns a filtered DbSet. The code, so far, is:

```
    public IEnumerable<Pesquisa> Pesquisas { 
        get {
            PrometheusDBContext db = new PrometheusDBContext();
            var temp = db.Pesquisas;

            if ((this.Filtro.Nome != null) && (this.Filtro.Nome.Trim() != ""))
            {
                temp = (temp.Where(p => SqlFunctions.PatIndex(this.Filtro.Nome, p.Nome) > 0) as DbSet<Pesquisa>);
            }

            if ((this.Filtro.CodTipoPesquisa != null) && (this.Filtro.CodTipoPesquisa.Trim() != ""))
            {
                temp = (temp.Where(p => p.CodTipoPesquisa == this.Filtro.CodTipoPesquisa.Trim()) as DbSet<Pesquisa>);
            }

            if ((this.Filtro.IDStatusPesquisa != null) && (this.Filtro.IDStatusPesquisa > 0))
            {
                temp = (temp.Where(p => p.IDStatusPesquisa == this.Filtro.IDStatusPesquisa) as DbSet<Pesquisa>);
            }

            if ((this.Filtro.DataCriacao_Inicial != null) && (this.Filtro.DataCriacao_Final != null))
            {
                temp = (temp.Where(p => (p.DataCriacao >= this.Filtro.DataCriacao_Inicial) && (p.DataCriacao <= this.Filtro.DataCriacao_Final)) as DbSet<Pesquisa>);
            }
            else 
            {
                if (this.Filtro.DataCriacao_Inicial != null)
                {
                    temp = (temp.Where(p => p.DataCriacao >= this.Filtro.DataCriacao_Inicial) as DbSet<Pesquisa>);
                }
                if (this.Filtro.DataCriacao_Final != null)
                {
                    temp = (temp.Where(p => p.DataCriacao <= this.Filtro.DataCriacao_Final) as DbSet<Pesquisa>);
                }
            }

            return temp
                .Include(p => p.Usuario)
                .Include(p => p.StatusPesquisa)
                .Include(p => p.TipoPesquisa)
                .Include(p => p.ModeloTermoAdesao)
                .Include(p => p.Pacientes)
                .ToList();
        }
```

Problem is: everytime one of the attributes is filled with some value (i.e.: this.Filtro.Nome = "test" ), the ToList() raises an ArgumentNullExcpetion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't cast to DbSet at the end of each line. 
Also, declare

```
IQueryable<Pesquisa> temp = db.Pesuisas;

// your code follows.
```

The reason behind it is that although you start with a DbSet, applying operators changes its type. Your dynamic cast returns null then.

Comment: Yep. It did it... Thanks a lot.

Comment: So according to the reason i was getting the error, if i started aplying a "where" method to the var declaration of the temp, it should be ok too, right? 
[Like: "var temp = db.Pesquisas.Where(p => p.IDPesquisa > 0);"]

Comment: Yes, it should be ok.